# Change color of navigation buttons of default mail composer

Tags: iphone

I have used navigation bar category to color my navigation bar. All works fine. 
But when I add mail composer picker, navigation bar gets coloured but buttons are default blue. 
How can I change those?

I have used image in navigation bar in category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mailer.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor yourColor];
```

This might help you :)

Comment: beware: it is available only in iOS (5.0 and later).